# Rails textarea and content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to use one textarea and few `content_for`.

My goal is split content for few parts

I want to use like it

`content_for :header`, 
`content_for :body`

and

`content_for :footer`

so i want to write full text and separate it

```
yield :header
```

then some content

```
yield :body
```

then images

and `yield :footer`

i dont want to create textarea for each `content_for`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do exactly what you're saying. See the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method) and the [API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for). I tend to use `content_for` instead of `yield` like this (from the docs):

```
<% content_for :not_authorized do %>
   alert('You are not authorized to do that!')
<% end %>
```

Then

```
<%= content_for :not_authorized if current_user.nil? %>
```